# Please explain this php substr code for a total beginner

Tags: php

```
<?php
$imgdir = 'img/';
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
{
//please explain this part!!
if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
    in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
{$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}

$totimg = count($a_img);
for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "'/></li>"
;}?>
```

I understand, that this is like babysteps, but my problem is: I read php manual, but I don't really understand why the substr part is as it is! Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain to you like in baby language :D

substr takes two argument, a string and a number. String is the text or characters like file names etc, and number is the number of characters you want to take of it.

If the number is a positive number, then it will be taking characters from left side and if number is negative, then it will be taking from right side. In your code:

```
substr($imgfile,-3)  // takes three characters from left
```

it means, to take the last three characters of the image file name, which is the extension of the file, and

```
substr($imgfile,-4)  // takes four characters from right side
```

means take last four characters.

In you allowed types array :

```
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');
```

you have three characters extensions and one four characters extension, so those two substr are used for those purpose.

I hope i explained it in simple words for you.

Thank you

Comment: Yes! Baby language is very welcome! :) Thank you so much! I just started learning php and sometimes feel just dumb! But I will get better! Thank you so so much!

Comment: In fact substr is taking 3 arguments. (string, start, length)

Comment: you are welcome. Try to read a book, like Teach yourself PHP in 24 hours, or any other basic and good book. Also lynda videos on php are also very good.

Answer (score 2):

It is checking the last 3 then the last 4 characters of the filename to get the extension and seeing if it is inside an array of allowed types.

However it would probably be better to use `pathinfo()` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($imgfile);
if( in_array(strtolower($path_parts['extension']),$allowed_types) ) {
    $a_img[] = $imgfile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am trying like crazy to understand php! You guys really help!

Answer (score 0):

`substr($imgfile,-3)`; is equals `substr($imgfile, strlen($imgfile)-4);`

This means you only receive the last 3 chars of your string. 
In this case the author first checks the last 3 and then the last 4 chars to look if it is an allowed extension.

For further info check doc again: [string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)

Comment: So it is checking if the extension is as in allowed types array?

Comment: Yes you are right. But it would be better to use `explode(".", $imgfile)` or `pathinfo()` like @Pitchinnate said.

Comment: Ok, will give it a shot! :)